Is there a simpler way than my current implementation of locking the screen orientation using Angular?
I feel that my current implementation in typescript is a bit excessive and that it can be done much simpler.  I am using angular 17.
I just want to have something like:
if(condition){
lockScreenInPortrait()
}

This is my service right now:
 import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
    
    type OrientationLockType = "portrait-primary" | "portrait-secondary" | "landscape-primary" | "landscape-secondary";
    
    // interface should mirror the properties of the browser's ScreenOrientation API.
    interface ScreenOrientationExtended extends ScreenOrientation {
      lock(orientation: OrientationLockType): Promise<void>;
      unlock(): void;
    }
    
    // Update the ScreenExtended interface to use the correct ScreenOrientation type
    interface ScreenExtended extends Screen {
      orientation: ScreenOrientationExtended;
    }
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root',
    })
    export class OrientationService {
    
      async lockOrientation(shouldLock: boolean): Promise<void> {
        // type assertion to inform TypeScript about the expected type
        const screenExtended = screen as unknown as ScreenExtended;
    
        if (shouldLock) {
          try {
            // Attempt to lock the screen orientation
            await screenExtended.orientation.lock('portrait-primary');
     
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error locking the screen orientation:', error);
          }
        } else {
          // Unlock the orientation if supported and if previously locked
          if (screenExtended.orientation.unlock) {
            screenExtended.orientation.unlock();
          }
        }
      }
    }


The method should be for single purpose. I think it is better to implement lock() and unlock() separately.
